# Open a new window on click submit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello i want to open new window on click of submit button using ruby on rails, Here is my code

```
<div class="actions">
        <%= f.button :submit,:class => 'btn btn-md btn-success' do %>
          <i class='fa fa fa-plus'></i> Create New Window
        <% end %>
</div>
```

i have tried :target => "_blank" in submit, but it doesnt work, please help me

Comment: what you want to show in new window..??

Comment: i want to go to index page, after clicking submit.

Comment: do u want to open only new window for index page.. or you want to redirect to index page after form submit.??

Comment: ya, i want to open only new window for index page on click of submit

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use formtarget="_blank".

```
<%= form_for @my_obj do |f|

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit,:class => 'btn btn-md btn-success', :formtarget => "_blank" do %>
      <i class='fa fa fa-plus'></i> Create New Window
    <% end %>
</div>
```

This link will help you http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formtarget.asp

Comment: Note @rohin-arka's answer below in order to make any form submission open in a new window. The trick is to pass `target: '_blank'` as a sub-hash of the `html` key.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try target sending target as _blank parameter in form_for not in submit button.

```
<%= form_for @my_obj, html: { target: "_blank" } do |f|

<div class="actions">
        <%= f.button :submit,:class => 'btn btn-md btn-success' do %>
          <i class='fa fa fa-plus'></i> Create New Window
        <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass `target="_blank"` in your form

for an example

```
<form action="..." ...
onsubmit="window.open('google.html', '_blank', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');return true;">
```

Try this one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the window conditionally, depending upon successful submission of your form you might:

- Set `remote: true` on your form
- Add a `format.js { render :show, status: :ok }` to your controller
- Add a `show.js` file that runs `window.open` per the reply by Vishal

This is one way you can get started with AJAX forms